# JHipster alerts not displaying

Tags: jhipster

I know how the alerts should work, as I'm copying an example of them in "user-management.component.html". But I see them working correctly on the user management page, and I can NOT get them to work on a new page I created.

Here's my HTML:

`<jhi-alert></jhi-alert>`

And here's my JS (and again this exact code works on the user-management page):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JhiAlertService, JhiEventManager } from 'ng-jhipster';
'@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-home',
    templateUrl: './volumefinder.component.html',
})
export class VolumefinderComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private alertService: JhiAlertService
    ) {
        this.alertService.error("foo", "bar", null);
    }
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No errors. And I can inspect the "JhiAlertService" and I see that works properly (its the correct class etc...)

Comment: What version are you using? There where some issues with lazy loading angular modules (but in that case the alert where not showing in user management, but in all entity screens only). https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8498